# Why cant my gaming computer run Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My computer has 8Gb of ram and a Ryzen 5 processor. Its able to run Skyrim perfectly at default quality, yet it cant run Minecraft at its lowest quality. Any guesses as to why this is?

Comment: No java installed?

Comment: You need Java 8 to run Minecraft, are you sure that it's installed?

Comment: Yeah, we need some more info here,
Any errors popups?
You got java installed?

Answer (score 1):

You either: forgot to install java, have a malformed startup command, or (and this is least likely) some weird firmware/driver issue. To fix the first, download and install java. The second, create a new "installation" from the minecraft launcher (this should generate a new startup command). For the third, just update/install drivers as necessary, although I am almost 100% sure this is not your issue.